# worklight -error while accesing worklight server deployed on was

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

[/mobile/apps/services/api/BOMApp/common/query] failure. state: 500, response: Unique constrain: found 2 beans implementing inteface com.worklight.server.report.api.GadgetReportsService (in 4 spring application contexts). worklight.js:1097

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have several Worklight instances running on a server. Make sure that you got only one worklight-jee*.jar and only one .war deployed.

Comment: yeah may be i m not clear with the problem.Some times it is working fine and some times getting error as specified above...i deployed only one war still getting the problem....i am using worklight server on websphere application server